# Replace exterior wooden spigot cover on siding

Tags: exterior, siding, spigot

I have a spigot on the side of my house that leaked before I bought the house. I ordered a new "vacuum breaker float" to fix the leak. However the 6"x6" wooden panel on the side of the house is rotten.

[image: rotten spigot cover]

As far as I can tell this is a 6"x6" piece of wood with a working drip cap on top and some caulk around it. The siding is Hardie board. I'm thinking of removing the existing piece of wood and cutting a new 1"x6" piece of pressure treated pine with a skill saw to create a 6"x6" square (1" inch deep) to replace it. Then I would use some screws to fasten this new wood, caulk around it, then paint it.

I'm not sure about:

- Should I drill a hole in this new 6x6 square and remove the existing pipe or, more likely, cut the 6x6 square in half and make a hole in the middle so I can fit the two pieces around the pipe without disturbing it. If I cut the square in half, do I need anything other than wood glue to stick the two pieces together?
- Beyond caulking around the new wood I'm assuming I should add some silicon sealant around this plastic piece with slot screws going into the new wood.

If anyone knows how to approach this repair or if there's an easier/better fix I'd appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cutting the square in half is a wise decision. Instead of using silicone caulk use a polyurethane caulk like [Vulkem](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Vulkem-45-28-7-fl-oz-Limestone-Paintable-Advanced-Sealant-Caulk/3595630?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_221_Glue-Adhesives-Caulk-Repair-_-3595630-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw4NujBhC5ARIsAF4Iv6djFMrWgoiZrrhs7lL5cPsyh4cuq1WmQNo6XG1EIGJtkKtymLH_pmIaAjlzEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) ,  It's paintable,stays pliable, won't shrink and is adhesive. A few small nails and the vulkem around the pipe and behind the wood and you need nothing else.The wood block will be fully secured to the wall.  Wait 24 hours to paint. Done.